# SPARQL query with filter not exists

Tags: sparql, jena

I want to make a query that delivers all triples `(s,p,o)` fulfilling the following: There is a path from `s` to `o` via the predicate `p` of length of at least 2 edges, but the triple `(s,p,o)` does not exist.

My query looks as follows (`p` is `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/isPartOf>` here):

```
select ?s ?p ?o
WHERE { 
?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/isPartOf>/<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/isPartOf>+ ?o .
FILTER (NOT EXISTS {?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/isPartOf> ?o } )
}
```

I executed it via the Jena API and got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "select" "select "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    "\ufeff" ...
    "base" ...
    "prefix" ...
    "insert" ...
    "delete" ...
    <INSERT_DATA> ...
    <DELETE_DATA> ...
    <DELETE_WHERE> ...
    "load" ...
    "clear" ...
    "create" ...
    "add" ...
    "move" ...
    "copy" ...
    "drop" ...
    "with" ...
```

Comment: how do you parse the query? The syntax is correct and Jena is capable of parsing it. It's obvious from the error message that you use a SPARQL Update parser here which is clearly wrong. So dont use `UpdateAction.parseExecute` (or whatever you do) but `QueryFactory.create` (or similar)

Comment: by the way, a SELECT query doesn't return proper triples, that would be the job of a `CONSTRUCT` query. Moreover, `?p` is not bound in your query and no, you can't use variables in property paths to answer that in advance

Comment: ok, that was a stupid mistake, now it works :)